# how to stop the automatic tab closing in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\DELL\\PycharmProjects\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("http://www.letskodeit.com")
```

i had written the code like this and the code was executed without any errors ,but the concern is the website which it was opening automatically by "get" command is closing automatically after it was opened .
please help me in sorting out this problem

please help me in sorting out the issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the driver to stay open, you have to use the `detach` option when creating the driver instance.
As following:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path="C:\\Users\\DELL\\PycharmProjects\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("http://www.letskodeit.com")
```